# Ace Editor Autocompletion on select event

Tags: autocomplete, autosuggest, ace-editor

I am using ACE Editor & I have set following properties to enable autocompletion.

```
editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true
});
```

I want to add some functionality when user selects any of the autocompletion suggestion (by pressing enter or by using mouse). 
Could you please suggest me how can I implement this? Is there any event like onSelect ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no `onSelect` event for now https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.9/lib/ace/autocomplete.js#L183
You can try using completer.insertMatch or make a pull request adding the event.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am very new to ace editor. could you please tell me more about  **completer.insertMatch** ?

Comment: Perhaps code snippet from https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/2437#issuecomment-90719158 would be helpful